# WooCommerce order action hook error when complete order

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

So I'm using the woocommerce_order_actions hook to add a few new actions to the list. This all works fine, but now I get a weird bug when I try to change the order status to completed.

```
function add_order_actions($actions) {
    global $theorder;
    $user = wp_get_current_user();

    if(array_intersect(['administrator'], $user->roles)) {
       $actions['wc_action_reset_test'] = 'Reset test result';
    }

    return $actions;
}
add_action('woocommerce_order_actions', 'add_order_actions');
```

So if I change the order status to completed now and press update, it will show me a critical error page from wordpress. Not really giving an error message.

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: Please check [Debugging in WordPress](https://wordpress.org/support/article/debugging-in-wordpress/)

Comment: Thanks @Bhautik . I got the debug mode to work and now I see that in the same script it's trying to include a SMTP class wich already exists in another plugin. So that's probably why it's giving me the fatal error.

Answer (score 1):

Difficult to say without getting an error but you could add some extra checks to prevent an error, comment added with explanation in the code.

- [is_object](https://www.php.net/is_object) - Finds whether a variable is an object
- [wp_get_current_user()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_current_user/) - Retrieve the current user object.

```php
function action_woocommerce_order_actions( $actions ) {
    global $theorder;

    // This is used by some callbacks attached to hooks such as woocommerce_order_actions which rely on the global to determine if actions should be displayed for certain orders.
    if ( ! is_object( $theorder ) ) {
        $theorder = wc_get_order( $post->ID );
    }

    // Get current user
    $user = wp_get_current_user();

    // Safe usage
    if ( ! ( $user instanceof WP_User ) ) {
        return;
    }

    // In array
    if ( in_array( 'administrator', $user->roles ) ) {
        $actions['wc_action_reset_test'] = __( 'Reset test result', 'woocommerce' );
    }

    return $actions;
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_actions', 'action_woocommerce_order_actions', 10, 1 );
```